# Why can't Windows 7 extract files from my password protected zip-file created using DotNetZip?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

I'm creating a password protected zip-file using [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). When I try to extract the files I'm met with an "unspecified error". Why is that?

```
using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
{
    zipFile.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zipFile.Password = "pangolin";

    foreach(var file in someFileCollection)
    {
        zipFile.AddEntry(file.Name, file.Stream);
    }

    zipFile.Save(aPathOnDisk);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because Windows and more specifically Windows Explorer can't handle AES-level encryption and requires the encryption level to be set to PkzipWeak which is documented as "*Traditional or Classic pkzip encryption.*"

```
zipFile.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.PkzipWeak;
```

According to the documentation on the EncryptionAlgorithm enumeration:

> [...] if you produce a zip archive using WinZipAes256, you will be able to open it in Windows Explorer on Windows XP and Vista, but you will not be able to extract entries; trying this will lead to an "unspecified error".

Note: popular third-party archive-utilities such as WinZip or 7-Zip can handle AES-encryption just fine. It's Windows Explorer that's the weak card in the deck.

Comment: Looks like 7-Zip can handle it, and I would guess WinZip and probably WinRar as well.

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes. It's specifically Windows Explorer that's weak in this regard.

Comment: On a related note, if using 7zip to password protect an archive, you have to use encryption method "ZipCrypto" instead of "AES-256". This answer helped me figure that out.

Comment: Seems like Macs have the same problem as Windows. I didn't create the file, but I encountered one that both Windows and Mac would throw a permissions error on when trying to extract. WinRar was able to prompt for password and handle it properly.